# Ruby on Rails - Show external JSON code in view

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I get this External `JSON` from an external `API` service (that I'm using)

```
{
    "result": {
        "2332860": {
            "id": 2332860,
            "name": "NAME 1",
            "capping": {
                "quantity": 1,
                "frequency": 1440
            },
            "status": 0,
            "price": 159,
            "publisher_ad_types": []
        },
        "2335970": {
            "id": 2335970,
            "name": "NAME 2",
            "capping": {
                "quantity": 1,
                "frequency": 1440
            },
            "status": 0,
            "price": 159,
            "publisher_ad_types": []
        },
        "2343470": {
            "id": 2343470,
            "name": "NAME 3",
            "capping": {
                "quantity": 1,
                "frequency": 1440
            },
            "status": 0,
            "price": 170,
            "publisher_ad_types": []
        }
    },
    "request_metadata": {
        "limit": 50,
        "offset": 0,
        "count": 11
    }
}
```

I get this output by having the code blow in my `controller`:

```
api = HTTParty.get("https://api.external-service.com/v2/",headers: {"Authorization" => "api_token_hhs762jh97shakkaa"})

render :json => api
```

What I'm looking to do is to be able to show each *block* for itself in my view.

How am I able to achieve that?

Any help or tips is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you have a JSON response, why can't you just iterate over the map and render whatever HTML you want? Or do you want to show the JSON itself (like as a code block)?

Comment: Hello @DaveNewton I have tried with map but for some reason I get undefined map method in my view. Not sure if I do something wrong :)

Comment: Most likely you did, but as I cannot see your screen, it's impossible to help.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for your comment. Sorry I was wrong, I didn't get error, but I had problem with how to select each block and *call* each elements in block like, `id`, `name` etc. In my view I did `@api.map do |line|` `%p=line`, this one still shows me the whole `JSON`code and when I do `%p=line['name']` I get error: **no implicit conversion of String into Integer**. So basically my biggest issue now is how to *call/select* each element on each block like `name`, `id` etc. Thanks for your help

Comment: Here's some tips. 1) Put a `binding.pry` (or whatever you're using) in your controller or view and *look at the data* to see what you have. It's a map. The first key is `result`. You want to iterate over that. 2) `result` is also a map. If you iterate (you want `each`, not `map`, btw, if you're not collecting results) over a map your block will take `|key, val|`, e.g., the ID, and the object referenced by that key. 3) Now that you have each result's values you can pull stuff out of it like `val['name']`. 4) The REPL is your friend: use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveNewton for taking your time :) I will try your tips and hopefully getting this done

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your help. I managed to get each block for `result` & `request_metadata ` by doing this in my view: `- @api.each do |a, b|` `- b.each do |key, val|` `%p=key` `%p{style: 'color:blue;'}= val.to_s`. As mentioned I get the blocks (bot for `result` and `request_metadata`), but when I do `val['name']` I get error: **no implicit conversion of String into Integer** and I only want the `result` block and not `request_metadata`. Hope you can give me some more pointers :) appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moved to answer for formatting.)

`@api.each` will iterate over the top-level object. There is are two key/value pairs: `result` and `request_metadata`. I don't know why you're converting it directly to a string; it's an object, and you don't want a string representation of it.

I don't know the type of `@api` in your scenario; if it's already parsed, that step can be skipped in the code below. (It should be by default under HTTParty as [shown in the docs](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/docs#parsing-json), if it isn't, you can parse it as I do. I took your value as a string, parsed it into a standard hash (e.g., not a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`; I don't recall what HTTParty returns), and started picking out some values as an example.

```
obj    = JSON.parse(s)
result = obj['result']

result.each do |id, val|
  id, name = val['id'], val['name']
  puts "ID:   #{id}"
  puts "Name: #{name}"
end
```

Running this code produces the following:

```
ID:   2332860
Name: NAME 1
ID:   2335970
Name: NAME 2
ID:   2343470
Name: NAME 3
```

In your view instead of doing this you'd want something more like (this is off-the-cuff):

```
<ul>
  <% result.each do |id, val| %>
    <li><%= val['id'] %> - <%= val['name'] %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

If you only care about the `result` then that's the only thing that should be exposed to the view. If you have a domain object that represents this data then it should be converted before passing it to the view.

Note that my code is not running under Rails, but the idea is precisely the same.

*[(Complete example here.)](https://github.com/davelnewton/stackoverflow/blob/master/ruby/51225050/standalone_example.rb)*

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveNewton. Appreciate you took your time :). Works perfectly